# Linq join and order by

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have files in one table and file actions in another. I want to get the most recent file that Jeff has taken action on that has a status of 4. In SQL, that looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 files.* 
FROM files 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fileActions ON files.FileId = fileActions.FileId
WHERE fileActions.ActionTaker = 'Jeff'
    AND files.FileStatus = 4
ORDER BY fileActions.ActionDate DESC
```

How would I express this same query in Linq?

I've tried a number of things, but I can't even get it to compile. I feel like this is the closest I have come thus far, but obviously "top" isn't a linq syntax word, so I have a good way to go:

```
var file = from f in context.Files
           join fa in context.FileActions on f.FileId equals fa.FileId
           where fa.ActionTaker == "Jeff"
           where f.FileStatus == 4
           orderby fa.ActionDate descending
           select top 1 f;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean: `var file  = (your_query).Take(1)` ?

Comment: Sigh... Yes. Yes I do. Thank you. I went with the FirstOrDefault, but once I wrapped the whole thing in parens, the world was my oyster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var file = (from f in context.Files
            join fa in context.FileActions on f.FileId equals fa.FileId
            where fa.ActionTaker == "Jeff" && f.FileStatus == 4
            orderby fa.ActionDate descending
            select f).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Man, I was so close! I am used to using lambda expression, so I didn't think about wrapping the linq.

Comment: All of the answers were valid, but since I used this one, marked as answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question...

```
 var file = (from f in context.Files
             join fa in context.FileActions on f.FileId equals fa.FileId
             where fa.ActionTaker == "Jeff" && f.FileStatus == 4
             orderby fa.ActionDate descending
             select new { Value1 = fa.Id, Value2 = f.Id }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You did. I don't need to select into an anonymous type. For my case, a type of Files was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var file = (from f in context.Files
           join fa in context.FileActions on f.FileId equals fa.FileId
           where fa.ActionTaker == "Jeff"
           && f.FileStatus == 4
           orderby fa.ActionDate descending
           select  f).first();
```

Comment: Thanks! It may be null, so a FirstOrDefault() is appropriate for my case.